# how to make a div disappear/appear on hovering on other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to display the line when I hover over my div circle?

```css
#line {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id='circle'>
  <div id= 'line'>
```

Comment: There's no HTML? Why don't you guys read the rules on [ask] before asking?

Comment: That's not a valid HTML. Can you please post the full code? And be very clear and specific on which div to be hovered and which should get hidden.

Comment: You deleted previous version of this question asked a little while ago and did very little to improve this version from the last. Nor did you show any attempt to resolve this yourself. This isn't a coding service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery you can use:

```
var enterHandler = function(){
   $("#line").show();
};

var leaveHandler = function(){
   $("#line").hide();
};

$("#circle").hover(enterHandler, leaveHandler);
```

Comment: Seriously you need jQuery and JavaScript for such a simple one? Can't you use CSS alone?

Comment: Yes Praveen, you will need Javascript for this. If you have anything constructive to add please feel free.

Comment: Buddy, please, kindly check my answer. You don't need JavaScript for this. CSS is enough. JS and DOM Manipulation is very costly things for a browser. Do you agree?

Comment: If they are nested then yes but that was not clear in the question. It is quite possible that the circle could be on a completely different part of the page.

Comment: In that case, I agree with you buddy. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

First thing, with your code, it is not clear if the `<div>`s are siblings are nested. I will give you the solution for both.

**Nested**

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #99c;
}
#line {
  display: none;
  background: #9c9;
}
#circle:hover #line {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='circle'>
  <div id='line'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Siblings**

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #99c;
}
#line {
  display: none;
  background: #9c9;
}
#circle:hover + #line {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='circle'>
</div>
<div id='line'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can simply try:

```
$('#circle').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('#line').show();
});

$('#circle').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#line').hide();
});
```

Comment: Well the question wasn't clear enough, and using javascript and jQuery will not be affected by the order of the elements, especially if there are other elements in between.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be simplest.

```
$('#circle').hover(function(){
    $('#line').css('display','inline');
});
```

or whatever display property you are going for.

Comment: Seriously you need jQuery and JavaScript for such a simple one? Can't you use CSS alone?

Comment: Praveen is wrong, but this is also not quite correct as you do not have a handler to hide the line again on mouse exit.

Comment: @RichardGuy Kindly take the constructive comment. If it was rude, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in script tag and use onmouseover and onmouseout events

```
<script>
    function hidediv() {
        document.getElementById('line').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function showdiv() {
        document.getElementById('line').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

    <div id='circle' onmouseover="hidediv();" onmouseout="showdiv();" > this is circle
        <div id= 'line'>this is line
        </div>
    </div>
```